# Return HTML or build HTML using javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am returning data about contacts to build a list

the basic html looks like

```
{repeat:20}
<div class="contact">
  <a rel="123">FirstName LastName</a>
  <div class="info">
    {repeat:5}
    <div>
      <div class="infoLabel">Age:</div>
      <div class="infoPiece">56</div>
    </div>
    {endrepeat}
  </div>
</div>
{endrepeat}
```

> The {repeat:20} is not actual code
> That block of code is repeated 20 times

My question is.

What is more benificial:

1. Create the markup server side, return the actual html.
2. Return Json data with the information and build the list client side.

---

**For the purpose of this discussion let us assume some constants**

- Server load is not an issue (we are using a high performance server)
- The returned data is for display purposes only (not to be manipulated)
- We are not factoring in users without javascript enabled.
- We are not factoring in any browsers < Internet Explorer 7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As most of the times during web development, you need to decide what is more important to you.

If you're just after performance no matter what, it is of course faster to do all the render action on your server and just deliver HTML code. But this in turn, most times costs flexability plus, you've got more traffic over the wire.

On the other hand, just sending JSON data for instance and do the render stuff on the client, is much less traffic over the wire, but it's more CPU load on the clientside. Browsers (DOM + ECMAscript) have increased performance like a lot over the past years and month, so it is what lots of applications do.

But this is not the end of story. JSON is optimized, but not highly optimized. Again if you're **really** after performance you need to create your own transport of data. For instance

```
|box1|item1|item2
```

is less code then JSON notation

```
'{"box1": ["item1", "item2"]}'
```

This of course is highly specific, but it saves lots of traffic if we're going really big. I recommend the book **High performance Javascript** by Nicholas C. Zakas. Execellent book about this topic.

Comment: +1 Great answer from a performance perspective. I also want to add that the decision between HTML and JSON also depends on whether the data is static and purely for display purposes, or whether you want manipulate it later.

Answer (score 3):

If you're planning to do intensive AJAX tasks, such adding new records, edit them on the fly, etc., then I suggest you to load an empty page, that calls an script that returns an array of dictionaries by JSON, and then using the [Template](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/) (beta) system implemented in jQuery recently, or implement one yourself, having a hidden element, with spans/divs/tds tagged with classes, and cloning and filling it each time a new record arrives.

On the other hand, if you're going to keep this static, just use HTML.

This is how I manage templating. This is an efficient way because the DOM elements does exists in the DOM tree, and cloning is less expensive than parsing an string that contains the elements.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                $contactTemplate = $("#contact_template")
                function makeContactElement(data) {
                    var $newElem = $contactTemplate.clone(true)

                    $newElem.attr("data-id", data.id)
                    $newElem.find(".name").text( data.firstName + " " + data.lastName )

                    for(var i in data.info) {
                        $newElem.find(".info").append( makeInfoElement(data.info[i]) )
                    }

                    return $newElem
                }

                $infoTemplate = $("#info_template")
                function makeInfoElement(data) {
                    var $newElem = $infoTemplate.clone(true)

                    $newElem.find("infoLabel").text(info.label)
                    $newElem.find("infoPiece").text(info.piece)

                    return $newElem
                }

                $.getJSON('/foo.bar', null, function(data) {
                    for(var i in data) {
                        $("#container").append( makeInfoElement(data[i]) )
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .template { display: none; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container">
        </div>

        <!-- Hidden elements -->

        <div id="contact_template" class="contact template">
          <a rel="123" class="name"></a>
          <div class="info"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="info_template" class="template">
          <div class="infoLabel"></div>
          <div class="infoPiece"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, when you create a new record, just fill a data object with the information, and you'll sure that all the element flow will be generic.

Using `.clone(true)` opens the door to make generic events instead of binding a live event, which is more expensive.

For example, if you want to make a button to delete a record:

```
<script ...>
...
$("#contact_template .delete").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parents("contact").attr("data-id")
    $.post('/foo.bar', { action: delete, id: id }, function() { ... })
    return false
})
</script>
...
<div id="contact_template" class="contact template">
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Link that further describes efficient ways of adding elements to the DOM http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=3

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would create it server side and return the html.  The biggest reason being that otherwise your site is useless to anyone who has javascript disabled.  It would also be largely invisible to search engines.

Comment: I get the feeling that all this is loaded dynamically anyway.

Comment: @Box9 you are correct. Also, if a search engine found a way to this page in the first place I would be rather worried!

Comment: @Box9 and @Hailwood - both good points, so my reasons probably don't apply, but I'll leave the answer here anyways since it might apply to the more general situation (even if not for your situation specifically)

Comment: I don't think we're living in a time where considering "turned of Javascript" is still worth to think about.

Answer (score 1):

i'd say do it server-side.... as JS might increase your page-loading time...

Comment: Are you referring to initial page load time? With regards to downloading the Javascript. Most high performance web applications use compressors, this, combined with caching and high internet speeds these days almost completely negate's this as a factor.

Comment: uhm. yeah, you're right. when I rethink my answer, I should have shut up ^^

Answer (score 1):

Page loading time wouldn't factor into my decision if i were you. I'd think about how easy it would be to maintain. I think doing it serverside would make things a lot easier. No need to have templates for your javascript to parse.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are asking for an opinion, not a specific answer to a technical question. So here's my opinion.

The trend these days is towards web applications, with more client-side functionality and off-line functionality. Therefore, I would do it client side and send JSON. That is also more scalable since the server side does less work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not worried about server-side load and have CPU cycles to spare, go ahead and let your backend do the bulk of the work.  The application will be snappier and respond faster.  You have to keep in mind network utilization, however.  Throwing JSON strings back and forth is extremely efficient and reduces network load, but requires the client to do more work.  As stated in this discussion, browsers are extremely fast these days.  JavaScript implementations in Chrome, FF4 and IE9 are some of the fastest we have ever seen.

My suggestion is to do a small benchmark with your application as-is, and see how it performs.  Try to hit the two variants with many requests to see things under load.  It will really depend on your particular application.

Comment: A small benchmark, e.g. create two scripts, one that will build the list using javascript, another that will simply append the required contact details. Could do, How many cycles would you say as a safe benchmark?